# Cannot parse feed

Tags: simplepie

I'm trying to parse this feed http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/newcastle-united/rss.xml
I get this message "A feed could not be found at http://. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are certain this URL is a real feed."
If I use force_feed I get an error "This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: Mismatched tag at line 27, column 8" but looking at the xml I can't see any errors. Indeed, checking at http://validator.w3.org/ seems to validate fine. 
Any suggestions? 
I'm running the latest version of simplepie downloaded a few days ago.

Comment: Please make sure that if you ask a question, you include valid code to reproduce the problem that you're having. It appears that the error message is saying that a feed cannot be found at `http://`, which to me implies that you're passing invalid data to the SimplePie API when telling it which URL to parse. However, without your code in the question we cannot verify that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem when I stripped out the code to create a test case. The url being loaded was http://www.bbc.co.uk//sport/football/teams/newcastle-united/rss.xml (notice the double forward slash). simplepie seems to not be dealing with this gracefully. Removing the double slash fixes the problem